# Quite difficult positioning of midcontent in a fullwidth image

Tags: css, html

[image]

So, i have the following design. I'm unsure on how to solve this design. I have the following thoughts on it:

The people in the back can be a static image if i want it to be. I do have a CMS system, which my customer can use to upload the images if anyone of you shows me an example where i need the peopleimages to be added one by one.

My first thought was to include the red part in the background image, however, this makes both the people and the red part quite poor quality on big screens(1920>). The text should be retrieved from my CMS system and positioned like it is on the image.

1. As you may see, the red boxes are the same width as the peoplepictures. This means percent width will be hard if they are 2 different images.
2. The images of people should fit the whole browser screen. I don't care if some people fall out of the picture. The image shows that some people are already outside(the image is made that way).
3. The content should have a parallax effect, but is not absolutely necessary.

My second thought was to make the peoplespictures one by one, and use isotopes for good positioning. But, that will make it hard to fit the whole browser-screen. If one bottom row goes to the right, it wont be full height anymore.

If i use the red part as one image, and use the whole peoplepicture as one, i could use maximage on the peoplepicture. Then i could position the red part with percentage. But then again, that will make it very hard(i think) to actually have the same width on the red boxes as one personbox. It would however be easier to place the text, then if its one big image(including the red part).

Any suggestions, examples, tips etc? Any help will help!

Will bootstrap help me?

Comment: what have you tried so far? you need to show us code that you have worked on to demonstrate effort in finding the solution. Use stackoverflow to help troubleshoot your code when it is not working.

Comment: I did ask for suggestions, examples or tips. I did not ask for code. I would consider this okey. I have a limited time for this project, which means i can't try several things and fail. Hence, the question.

Comment: However, i might have a decent solution here http://banjo.no/consentra2/ You will need to re size the browser once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try http://jsfiddle.net/hMrN9/

Basically it is using some Jquery to size the blocks to squares (math adjustments could be used for a different ratio).

```
$( window ).load(function() {
    $(".consentra-box").height($(".consentra-box").width());
});
$( window ).resize(function() {
    $(".consentra-box").height($(".consentra-box").width());
});
```

The special tall box is created like this:

```
<div class="consentra-box consentra-red" >
     <div class="inner-red-box" style=" z-index: 999;"></div>
</div>
```

And the adjusted CSS:

```
.inner-red-box { background-color: #ee002f; height: 15%; margin-top: -15%; width: 100%; }
.consentra-box { position: relative; float: left; width: 14.28%; }
```

You just need to add your image elements at either backgrounds to the DIVs or IMGs set to 100%x100%

Comment: Thanks for that! But lets say i want the boxes to fill one full browser-height. I figured i would have to remove columns for that to work out. So i hid away 1 column of boxes on each side of the red part on high and low resolutions. However, i'm not sure on how to make the faces fit. The pictures have to show which kind of work they do, so only the faces wont suffice. I have made some changes, and here my current version: http://client.consentra.vitaminw.no PS. i have not removed columns on this version for high\low resolutions.

Comment: without using some javascript (like i used in my example) to maintain the aspect ratio, you will experience cropping or stretching of the picture blocks. My recommendations is using the JS i provided to maintain aspect ratio and adding in some conditional CSS (@media queries) to adjust visibility and size of the picture columns that are shown based on browser/device width.

Comment: Something like this: `@media (max-width: 600px) {  .box1, .box7 { display: none; } .consentra-box { width: 20%; }  }`  -- you would obviously need to add more, varied media queries to handle the behavior at various size points that you want to target -- i also gave each box a new class (box[1-7]) representing it's column number

Comment: I actually ended up doing exactly this! I'm doing the devices first, then ill make it decent for different ratios on desktop. Thanks again

Comment: glad it worked out for you... please post a link to the final version if possible... I know I would like to see the end product.